# How to add JavaScript highlighting inside of Underscore.js templates in Atom

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I'm wondering if there is a way to add syntax highlighting for JavaScript code inside of Underscore.js templates in Atom editor? I've searched for some plugins for that, but with no result.

I have a number of HTML files with Underscore.js templates inside of HTML, and the code looks like this:

```
<div>
  <% lists.forEach(list => {  %>
    <span id="list-<%= list.id %>"><%= list.name %></span>
  <% }); %>
</div>
```

So maybe there are some plugins that I've missed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing grammar to Html (Ruby - ERB). `Edit -> Select Grammar`